# How do I convert database query result to JSON contained in one single array?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm attempting to create a web app that displays records in my record collection stored in a database. I want to pull the rows from the database, convert them to JSON, then with Javascript write the JSON objects to an HTML page. Currently I have a php while loop writing the rows to an array..

```
<?php
include('./connection.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM voting";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if (!$result) die($mysqli->error);
$array = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $array[] = $row;
    echo json_encode($array);
} ?>
```

The while loop is writing each row to it's own array. I want to place all of the returned JSON objects into one array. How do I achieve this?

Comment: first, please provide the table structure or the result of the query as an example.. then your desired json result. its hard to think of a solution with very minimal information..

Comment: Move `echo json_encode($array);` outside the while loop.

Comment: The table structure is album, artist, year, image(URL), ID

I want the JSON object to look like 
"records": [
{
"artist": "..."
"album": "..."
...
}
{etc. Also when I move the echo json_encode outside the while loop nothing displays.

Comment: Are you putting it *after* the while loop?

Comment: When I place it after the while loop, after the }, nothing displays.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense at all that it's displaying something using the code in your question, but not if you put the `echo` after the `while` loop. Did you look at the outputted page source?

Answer (score 0):

php:

```
$array = array();
 while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
 $array[] = $row;
}
```

javascript:

```
<script>
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($array, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
</script>

console.log(data);
```

Comment: You should probably add a bit of text explaining your answer. Code-only answers are rarely useful.